# Ubuntu 11.10 PDF Booklet Format won't print

Tags: hp, pdf

I have Acroread (64 bit) installed on Ubuntu 11.10 and when trying to print a PDF document in Booklet format it just sits there in the print queue on a HP Deskjet 8500 saying "Processng".

Before when I was using Ubuntu 10.10 it would print without any problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why Acroread? What was wrong with the installed-out-the-box Evince? Can you test with that by right click the file and opening with "document viewer". At the moment it's hard to know if it's a printer issue or a Adobe problem.

Comment: Document Viewer (i.e. Evince) doesn't print in booklet format. That's why I installed Acroread.

Comment: If you noticed this issue after and update (which sometimes happens) or an upgrade as such, is a regression and it is considered a bug. Please report it. Bug reports ([How do I submit a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!